# MongoDB - convert string to timestamp, group by hour

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following documents stored in a collection:

```
{
  "REQUESTTIMESTAMP" : "26-JUN-19 01.34.10.095000000 AM",
  "UNHANDLED_INTENT" : 0,
  "USERID" : "John",
  "START_OF_INTENT_SKILL_CONVERSATION" : 0,
  "PROPERTYCODE" : ""
}
```

**I want to group this by the hour(which we will get from 'REQUESTTIMESTAMP')**

Earlier, I had this document stored in the collection in a different way, where I had a separate field for hours, and used that hours field to group:

**Previous aggregation query :**

```
collection.aggregate([
    {'$match': query}, {
        '$group': {
            "_id": {
                "hour": "$hour",
                "sessionId": "$sessionId"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.hour",
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Previous collection structure:**

```
{
  "timestamp" : "1581533210921",
  "date" : "12-02-2020",
  "hour" : "13",
  "month" : "02",
  "time" : "13:46:50",
  "weekDay" : "Wednesday",
  "__v" : 0
}
```

How can I do the above same **Previous aggregation query** with the new document structure (After extracting hours from '**REQUESTTIMESTAMP**' field?)

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your timestamp to `Date` object then take hour from your date object.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    '$match': query
}, {
    $project: {
        date: {
            $dateFromString: {
                dateString: '$REQUESTTIMESTAMP',
                format: "%m-%d-%Y" //This should be your date format
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            hour: {
                $hour: "$date"
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Then you saw the comment about "This should be your date format"

Comment: That's the format you're requesting for but not the format that has to be in the field !! Anyway O/p doesn't need that format, all he need is hours !! Also how to convert that string to date is also an unsolved question.. Check ref :: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/ , So that string is not acceptable, in least case if it is additionally it will have 00 as hours with given format..

Comment: @ZavenZareyan much thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this didn't work as expected. I got an error in the time format :
Error: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Error parsing date string '14-JUN-19 09.56.07.821000000 AM'; 3: Unexpected data found. 'J'; 9: Format literal not found ' '; 12: Trailing data '.'; 12: The parsed date was invalid '.'",
 "code" : 241,
 "codeName" : "ConversionFailure"
} : aggregate failed

Comment: @whoami / ZavenZareyan, any of you guys has a solution for the problem? Please let me know if you need any more inputs from my side. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Problem is months names are not supported by MongoDB. Either you write a lot of code or you use libraries like [moments.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/). First update your `REQUESTTIMESTAMP` to proper Date object, then you can group it.

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function (doc) {
   var d = moment(doc.REQUESTTIMESTAMP, "DD-MMM-YY hh.mm.ss.SSS a");
   db.collection.updateOne(
      { _id: doc._id },
      { $set: { date: d.toDate() } }
   );
})

db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { $hour: "$date" },
         count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
   }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you're not able to update DB with actual date field & still wanted to proceed with existing format, try this query it will add hour field extracted from given string field **REQUESTTIMESTAMP** :

**Query :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            hour: {
                $let: {
                    /** split string into three parts date + hours + AM/PM */
                    vars: { hour: { $slice: [{ $split: ["$REQUESTTIMESTAMP", " "] }, 1, 2] } },
                    in: {
                        $cond: [{ $in: ["AM", "$$hour"] }, // Check AM exists in array
                        { $toInt: { $substr: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$$hour", 0] }, 0, 2] } }, // If yes then return int of first 2 letters of first element in hour array
                        { $add: [{ $toInt: { $substr: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$$hour", 0] }, 0, 2] } }, 12] } ] // If PM add 12 to int of first 2 letters of first element in hour array
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sVYJI5czGOQ)